# Kivy popup with incorrect graphics

Tags: raspbian, display, python-3

I could not find anything related so I posted the same question on [stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64137563/kivy-popup-with-incorrect-grapics) to reach a wider range of experts on the matter. On Raspberry Pi4 with Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) I have Kivy setup the following way:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/pi/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-09-30_28.txt
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0rc1, git-Unknown, 20191231
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) 
[GCC 8.2.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/bin/python"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'3.1 Mesa 19.3.2'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'VMware, Inc.'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'llvmpipe (LLVM 9.0.1, 128 bits)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 1
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.40'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2(['text_pango'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Unpack subimage support is available
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
```

I did a fresh SDL2 and Cython 0.29.21 install. Regardless if I use the original 7" TFT display or a LCD (both on HDMI) sometimes randomly a popup comes up in a see-through version or without colors and does not cover the main screen. See the pictures below.

Some of my code to get an idea. Unfortunately I can not provide a bare minimum working sample.

```
# to avoid "segmentation error" due to raspbian version
os.environ["KIVY_WINDOW"] = "sdl2"

# uncommnent he two lines below when using the TFT display
from kivy.core.window import Window
#Window.fullscreen = 'auto'
#Window.show_cursor = False

# kivy modules first, if not Kivy may cause problems
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
from kivy.factory import Factory
kivy.require('2.0.0')

# main screen
class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name="MAIN SCREEN"
        super(Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

# popup class  
class RequestBox(Popup):
    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        super(RequestBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.obj = obj

# main app class 
class Touch(App):
    pauseFlag = False           # init set pause to OFF  
        
    MainScreenTitle = "MainScreenTitle"
    MainScreenLabel = "MainScreenLabel"
    MessageBoxTitle = "MessageBoxTitle"
    MessageBoxLabel = "MessageBoxLabel"
    MessageButtonConfirm = "CONFERMA"
    MessageButtonCancel = "CANCELLA"
    MessageButtonEnter = "ENTRA"
    MessageButtonExit = "ESCI"

    def build(self):
        sm = Builder.load_string("""
    
ScreenManager
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
    MainScreen:
        size_hint: 1, 1
        auto_dismiss: False
        title: app.MainScreenTitle       
        title_align: "center"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            spacing: 10
            #Label:
                #text: app.MainScreenLabel
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "horizontal"
                spacing: 10
                size_hint: 1, .8
                Image:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    center: self.parent.center
                    source: "ChemoMakerMark.jpg"
                    size_hint: 1, 1
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "horizontal"
                spacing: 10
                size_hint: 1, .2
                Button:
                    font_size: 50
                    text: app.MessageButtonExit  # exit app
                    on_press:
                        self.background_color = 0,255,0,1
                        app.exit()
                    
<RequestBox>:
    size_hint: 1, .7
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: app.MessageBoxTitle       
    title_align: "center"
    title_size: 30
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            font_size: '30sp'
            #text_size: self.size #aligns left
            text: app.MessageBoxLabel
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            spacing: 10
            size_hint: 1, .5
            Button:
                font_size: 50
                background_color: 0,204,0,1
                text: app.MessageButtonConfirm  # "CONFIRM"
                on_press:
                    self.disabled = True
                    self.background_color = 0,255,0,1
                    app.accept_request()
                    root.dismiss()
            Button:
                font_size: 50
                background_color: 204,0,0,1
                text: app.MessageButtonCancel  # "CANCEL"
                on_press:
                    self.background_color = 255,0,0,1
                    app.reject_request()
                    root.dismiss()

        """)

        return sm
```

What could be the problem?

[image: scr2]
[image: scr3]

Comment: we'll just wait and see what happens with SO ... might as well not duplicate efforts

Comment: So far suggested is a driver issue. Also to check the popup opens in the main thread.